# Where is the best place to put custom software?

Tags: software-installation, directory-structure

I know Linux is very permissive and allows customization at many levels but let's said that I have downloaded some `.tar.gz` files like for example phpStorm and Smargit (both have binaries and libraries used by software) and I want to use them as any other software installed through DNF. Where would you place the uncompressed files or how would you do this?

I've found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20600/should-i-put-application-into-usr-local-or-usr-local-share?rq=1) topic but I am not sure if `/opt` is the right place for put this kind of standalone software.

Comment: The tarballs (`.tar.gz` files) themselves have little bearing on where you should put them, instead the contents are important. Do the tarballs contain binaries? source code? packages?

Comment: @Centimane well them contains binaries since it's phpStorm and Smargit (non installable files, non packages)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should prefer to put your application folders in `/opt` which is exactly what you are asking for.

`/usr` (apart from `/usr/local`) is the folder in which the files and folders are maintained by package managers like `apt-get` for Debian or `yum` for CentOS.

Also, you may want to check [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

@ukil's answer is probably the most widespread (/opt)

/usr/local is also a commonly used location.